# 3D rotating object animation on iOS

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, 3d, rotation

I want to replicate the 3D rotating object shown at the 6th second of this [video](http://youtu.be/GL2fBQM7CIg?t=6s) on iOS. I don't have any 3D animations/games experience, so I don't know where to start. I have looked a little and found [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12667/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-using-touches-with-opengl) tutorial of Ray Wenderlich. I think I can change the shape from cube to a rectangular prism, and move it around while it's rotating, but I want it to have some logo, text, etc. on it in 3D. This is where I'm stuck.

Any suggestions or tutorials related to this kind of work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get familiar with general concepts of 3D programming first because your question is ambiguous. What do you mean by on it?

That cube is comprised of several different arrays of data defining different properties of each vertex on each triangular face. So if you want 3D text coming out of the cube you will need to redefine those arrays.

There are a tonne of resources for learning 3D programing and the concepts are generally universal.

Comment: I want to create exactly that animation in the video. No popping text or logos. Imagine a cube shaped statue which has a logo on it, like the Lamborghini logo in the video. And it rotates around itself and passes by.
One think I want to learn is that, do I have to generate all of these in code? For example how can I put a Lamborghini logo on that rotating cube?

Comment: "how can I put a Lamborghini logo on that rotating cube" - you need to change the texture. But the image in the NFS video is not simple a cube with a texture. There is normal mapping, diffused lighting and specular lighting used to create that animation at 00:06 in the video.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i have done for rotate cube. Hope it helps.

```
var cubeLayer = CATransformLayer()
var layer1 = CALayer()
var layer2 = CALayer()
var layer3 = CALayer()
var layer4 = CALayer()

var pt = CATransform3DIdentity
pt.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0
yourView.layer.sublayerTransform = pt

layer1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
layer1.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(layer1.transform, 0, 0, 100)
cubeLayer.addSublayer(layer1)

layer2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
layer2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
layer2.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(layer2.transform, -100, 0, 0)
layer2.transform = CATransform3DRotate(layer2.transform, .pi / 2, 0, 1, 0)
cubeLayer.addSublayer(layer2)

layer3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
layer3.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
layer3.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(layer3.transform, 100, 0, 0)
layer3.transform = CATransform3DRotate(layer3.transform, .pi / 2, 0, 1, 0)
cubeLayer.addSublayer(layer3)

layer4.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
layer4.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
layer4.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(layer4.transform, 0, 0, -100)
cubeLayer.addSublayer(layer4)

cubeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
yourView.layer.addSublayer(cubeLayer)
```

add gesture to your view and rotate it using swap gesture, using below code you can rotate cube from left to right.

```
let swiperight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swiperight))
swiperight.direction = .right
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(swiperight)

@objc func swiperight(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) { 
    self.cubeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.cubeLayer.transform, .pi / -1.5, 0, 1, 0)

    self.cubeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.cubeLayer.transform, .pi / 4
        , 0, 1, 0)

    self.cubeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.cubeLayer.transform, .pi / 2
        , 0, 1, 0)
}
```